# playframework, using forms to add/change something in a database

Tags: java, forms, playframework

I'm am trying to make a database with ploegen. Now I want to give every ploeg a value punten. I made the input form like this:

```
    <h1>Geef punten</h1>

        @form(routes.Application.geefPunten(ploegnaam, punten)) {
            @inputText(ploegForm("ploegnaam"))
            @inputText(ploegForm("punten"))
            <input type="submit" value="voeg punten toe">
    }
```

But when I try to run this, I get an error saying:

```
    not found: value ploegnaam
```

In my routes file I made this:

```
    # Ploegen
    GET     /ploegen                    controllers.Application.ploegen()
    POST    /ploegen                    controllers.Application.nieuwePloeg()
    POST    /ploegen                    controllers.Application.deletePloeg(id: Long)
    POST    /ploegen                    controllers.Application.geefPunten(ploegnaam: String, punten: Integer)
```

And this is the method which I made in my Application:

```
    public static Result geefPunten(String ploegnaam, Integer punten) {
    return TODO;
}
```

Can you tell me how to solve this error?

Comment: Seems like Play wants something in the RESTful mapping URL to know which parameters to pass to your method.

Comment: Do you have any parameters (like: @(ploegForm: Form[Ploeg])) in *.scala.html file defined? Show your Ploegen class.